# Create simple event handler like inotify in GDB

Tags: linux, gdb, filesystems, handler

I am facing situation where I have no ability to install systemtap inotify lsof and another fancy stuff. What I am trying to achieve is to monitor particular directory for changes. When some change will occur (file created, deleted ...) then I get some kind of report logged to file. Is this kind of event handling even possible to achieve using GDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no, this is not something gdb can do.

Comment: are you aware of another possible approach?

Comment: I don't know all of your constraints.  It seems weird that you cannot install another program.  Could you install some Python code and do it that way?

Comment: Probably yes. It is production that means that all change to system (installing new packages etc.) requires the approvement from customer. For this reason I would like to keep things as simple as possible. I think using python script would be fine. Also I am interested in this task personally so I would like to experiment with this on my own box. Thank you.